# Ограничение обращений к Telegram Bot

Tags: java, telegram-bot

Здравствуйте! Подскажите пожалуйста, как ограничить спам командами от пользователей боту? Просто на каждую команду создается свой поток, который выполняет метод команды и закрывается. Спам не мешает, если юзеров менее 10. Но если больше - начинаются задержки.

P. S. В мечтах сделать так: если юзер начал спамить, ему отправляется заглушка о спаме.

Comment: М, по потоку на каждую команду - это круто. Но в целом, у Вас видимо есть такая логика - пришла команда, ее чуточку распарсили, создали тред и на выполенение?

Comment: @KoVadim да. Именно так.. По другому не позволяет библиотека, да и оно удобно

Comment: @KoVadim кстати сделано это потому, что если не создавать поток, будет очередь :) А юзеров много очень (в связи с ресурсом, для которого бот и делается)

Comment: выходов несколько. Самое простое - сделать мапу, в которую заносятся пользователи и когда делали запросы. Это позволит делать ограничения по кол-ву запросов. Способ второй - ускорить выполнение запросов. Способ третий - переписать на нормальном языке.

Чем занимаются потоки? что они именно делают?

Comment: @KoVadim за мапу спасибо :) Возьму на заметку пока. Насчет ускорения - быстрее уже некуда.. А насчет нормального языка - вот тут обидно. Что не так в джаве?

Comment: что не так в джаве - это тема холивара и тут ее лучше не подымать. Лучше расскажите, что за задачи решает бот и почему они такие тяжелые?

Comment: @KoVadim бот выполняет функцию приложения для сайта. Сам сайт имеет множество разделов, каждый из которого - почти свой сервис. По запросу - бот парсит информацию с определенного раздела сайта, фильтрует ее и отдает пользователю. Почему потоки? Чтобы люди не ждали выполнения команд каждого.. Теоретически, сами потоки не тяжелые - но при спаме начинаются ощутимые тормоза (каждый ждет в районе 3 секунд ответа. +- секунда)

Comment: во... если сайт Ваш - задумайтесь о апи. Также, в любом случае следует подумать о кешировании.

Comment: @KoVadim сайт не мой. А вот насчет кеша думал. Но там очень часто меняются значения. А если попробовать пихать в кеш - то как лучше?

Comment: А кто его знает. С другой стороны, может быть 3 секунды достаточно. А может, поставить 3-4-5 серверов.

Comment: @KoVadim все таки попробую с мапой. Подумал - лучший вариант. Проверяем значение при новом месседже и если даты отличаются меньше чем на 5 секунд - отправляем заглушку. Вроде ничего?

Comment: нужно попробовать. Вполне может работать хорошо. Но можно кешировать не весь ответ, а его части.

Comment: @KoVadim спасибо за мапу :) Пойду пробовать. Если с ней не получится - попробую кеш...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вопрос решен:
Самый выгодный вариант - создать Map и в нее класть каждый запрос от нового пользователя + дату. В следующий раз, если он же и напишет, сравниваем дату в Map с датой текущего сообщения, и если разница между ними менее n-секунд, отправляем пользователю заглушку.

Answer (score 1):

Организуйте **очередь** - если выполняется 10 потоков (или столько, сколько можно обслуживать без потери производительности), то ставьте пользователя **в** **ожидание** (в очередь) и уведомляйте его об этом. Как только освобождается поток - берите запрос из очереди и запускайте новый поток.
Это проще и правильнее, чем отслеживать последний запрос, хранить эти состояния и тп.